# Where are the libc++ headers when cross-compiling with OSXCross on Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, clang, cross-compiling, libc++

This is what I'm doing:

```
SDK_URL=https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases/download/10.13/MacOSX10.10.sdk.tar.xz
git clone "https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross.git" osxcross
mkdir -p osxcross/tarballs
curl -sSL "$SDK_URL" -o "osxcross/tarballs/MacOSX10.10.sdk.tar.xz"
cd osxcross && UNATTENDED=1 ./build.sh
```

I thought I wouldn't need anything else to compile but then I get this error when building the project:

```
/home/travis/osxcross/target/bin/i386-apple-darwin14-c++ -o platform/osx/sem_osx.osx.tools.32.o -c -g3 -DDEBUG_ENABLED -DDEBUG_MEMORY_ENABLED -w -DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY -DZLIB_DEBUG -DFREETYPE_ENABLED -DDEBUG_MEMORY_ALLOC -DSCI_NAMESPACE -DENABLE_DEPRECATED -DAPPLE_STYLE_KEYS -DUNIX_ENABLED -DGLES2_ENABLED -DOSX_ENABLED -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -DTOOLS_ENABLED -DGDSCRIPT_ENABLED -DMINIZIP_ENABLED -DXML_ENABLED -DGLEW_STATIC -DGLEW_ENABLED -Icore -Icore/math -Ieditor -Idrivers -I. -Iplatform/osx -Ithirdparty/zlib -Ithirdparty/glew -Ithirdparty/freetype -Ithirdparty/freetype/include -Ithirdparty/libpng platform/osx/sem_osx.cpp
osxcross: error: cannot find libc++ headers
osxcross: error: while detecting target
```

I don't see anything related to the libc++ path in the [readme file](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross/blob/master/README.md), the only thing that came out when googling for a solution is that it could be a [bug in clang](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-bugs/2013-November.txt), but I'm not sure.

This is the output when I try to build on macOS passing -H to clang:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 core
 core/math
 editor
 drivers
 .
 platform/osx
 thirdparty/zlib
 thirdparty/glew
 thirdparty/freetype
 thirdparty/freetype/include
 thirdparty/libpng
 /Users/user/Downloads/osxcross-master/target/bin/../SDK/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Users/user/Downloads/osxcross-master/target/bin/../SDK/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include
 /Users/user/Downloads/osxcross-master/target/bin/../SDK/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

Comment: Pass `-H` (and perhaps `-v`) to your `i386-apple-darwin14-c++` cross-compiler.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I updated the question with the output (only the search list) when building on macOS. On Linux though, the build command fails right away.